# How can I hide row/column headers in a NatTable?

Tags: nattable

I want to be able to add options to a right click menu of the NatTable that when clicked will cause either the row or column headers to be hidden but can be brought back as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice is to operate on the corresponding `DataLayer` and modify the row height. Modifying the `IDataProvider` is typically not a good practice, as the `IDataProvider` is responsible for providing the data, not how the data should be rendered. So the following is an example of how to toggle the visibility of the column header layer (supposed that `hideHeader` is the flag to store the current state).

```
    Button hideButton = new Button(buttonPanel, SWT.PUSH);
    hideButton.setText("Hide/Show");
    hideButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            this.hideHeader = !this.hideHeader;
            if (this.hideHeader) {
                columnHeaderDataLayer.setDefaultRowHeight(0);
            } else {
                columnHeaderDataLayer.setDefaultRowHeight(20);
            }
            natTable.refresh(false);
        }
    });
```

I know users who even used that approach to implement some sort of transition by slowly reducing the height to 0.

Alternatively you could use the `RowResizeCommand` if the column header `DataLayer` is not known

```
    Button hideButton = new Button(buttonPanel, SWT.PUSH);
    hideButton.setText("Hide/Show");
    hideButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            this.hideHeader = !this.hideHeader;
            if (this.hideHeader) {
                natTable.doCommand(new RowResizeCommand(natTable, 0, 0));
            } else {
                natTable.doCommand(new RowResizeCommand(natTable, 0, 20));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by changing the logic in the getColumnCount() method in my RowHeaderDataProvider to return 0 when flagged to be hidden, or 1 when flagged to be not hidden. Same applies for the getRowCount() in my ColumnHeaderDataProvider.